# Make a list item hold a picture and a label below it

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists, css-position

I'm trying for the first time to code my design into HTML and CSS and I'm stuck at implementing this part:

[image]

I'm trying to build a list of these white boxes, I planned to give each item a white border to build my box but I'm unable to code the Label Tag to be centered horizontally and after changing the img Label to block display I'm unable to set an padding or margin to give a decent space between the label and the image.

This what I've have so far.

Html:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="container">

<ul class="grid">
    <li><img src="img/Icon-House.png"><label>Houses</label></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content{
    background-color: #e24840;
    width: 743px;
    height: 300px;

    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-left: 183px;
    border-radius: 4px; 
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 10px #888888;
}

.content ul {
    float: left;

}

.content li {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
}

.content img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: block;
}

.content label{
margin-top: 48px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why you use **label** if you don't have any related `form action` element

Comment: `.content ul` >> float left is not a proper way to style custom elements. I mean you could have `.content` on other pages too, targeting directly `ul` and `li` is bad design. Assign a special class to your special UL and go for it.

Comment: It's my first time to code to HTML but I thought it would be a good way to control the label position because if I do <img>House</img> I would have no control over the text position. couldn't find tutorials with the same case.

Comment: ahh got it, ok let me show a better implementation of the desired in a sec

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'm just trying to get it work and understand how the CSS works and I'll improve my design. but as far as I understand your comment is for the sake of a good design but it won't solve my problem, right ?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/muneho/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be using a `label` here but rather a `figure` to wrap the image and `figcaption`.

```css
.content {
  background-color: #e24840;
  width: 743px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 48px;
  margin-left: 183px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 10px #888888;
}
.content ul {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.content li {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 160px;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.content img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.content figcaption {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">

    <ul class="grid">
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-100-100-4.jpg" />
          <figcaption>Houses</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you include the CSS? It should work only with the HTML, no?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking...I just adapted the demo the OP supplied.

Comment: But the answer would be clearer if it includes only the portion of code that will achieve what e7na online asked. Is just a suggestion. I up voted it anyway.